# How can I set the value using variable in textfield inside the UIwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How can I set the value using variable in `textfield` inside the `UIWebview` in c# using **`javascript`**

```
NSString nSString = new NSString("HI");
wvEditor.EvaluateJavascript(" $('#content').redactor(\"insert.set\", '%nSString')");
```

Comment: Did you want use the value of  UITextField   to set the value of an input control in html  when you edit the UITextField?